# CSS - Rotar cada letra de Item de Menu HTML

Tags: css, css-transform

Tengo un menu normal de elementos al que quiero que cada letra de cada li a se rote -20 grados contra reloj.  Sin embargo estruxture el codigo y no funciona.

Normalmente podemos aplicar cambios a los elementos padres, sin embargo en el caso de los hijos de este elemento no funciona.

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>       
        .giro {
            transform: rotate(340deg);
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Horizontal Menu</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" id="i1">
                    <small class="giro">I</small>
                    <small class="giro">n</small>
                    <small class="giro">i</small>
                    <small class="giro">c</small>
                    <small class="giro">i</small>
                    <small class="giro">o</small>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

No entiendo porque no funciona la rotacion ya que si la aplico al elemento li si trabaja. La cosa esta es que necesito girar cada letra.

Gracias,

Answer (score 2):

Cambiando el diplay debería funcionar. Por ejemplo:

```
.giro {
    transform: rotate(340deg);
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Gracias  funciono al 100%,